# How to solve this error: Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file

Tags: forms, joomla3.0

I'm working on a Joomla component and I encountered a problem that absolutely have no idea how and why this is occurring and how to solve it.

I have two views showing a list from two different DB tables. One is called 'projects' and one is called 'fields'. The projects view is working and the fields view is not. The code from the fields view is copied from the projects view and all code of the files (controller, model, view, form.xml, table) is the same except for, the names, tablename and/or fieldname.

The error occurs when in the fields view this code fires:

```
$this->filterForm = $this->get('FilterForm');
```

Somehow it can't load a (or the) form.

If I comment out the line and the part in the `default.php` where the filter elements are, it works but without the filter options.

If I load the edit/new view (field), everything works/shows correctly so the form.xml is not incorrect/corrupt.

I've been rummaging through the library files but I can't find the form nor the code.

And somehow (but this has nothing to do with this problem) I can't find the file where the JViewLegacy class is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla will look for an xml definition of the filter form in models/forms/filter_xxx.xml (eg filter_fields.xml, filter_projects.xml). Do you have both xml files there?

The Joomla team have recently (v3.8 on, I think) changed a lot of their class names. You can find the match from the old to the new in libraries/classmap.php, where they set up the alias from the old to the new. The new name of JViewLegacy is HtmlView in the namespace Joomla\CMS\MVC\View and you'll find the source in libraries/src/MVC/View.

Comment: Thank you. There was indeed no 'filter_fields.xml' in the forms folder. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Hmm I'm getting same error at the line `parent::display($tpl);` at end of display() in view class. But I don't use any filters. Any idea what to search for? Why won't it tell me WHICH FILE couldn't be loaded?